# How do you work with filenames from a dask-scheduler to dask-worker

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I'm setting up an experiment where I have to process millions of files (images), the order the files are completed in does not matter.

I want the scheduler to provide workers with a filename that is accessible via a samba share. The scheduler can not itself run the tasks, only the workers. The workers are contained within a virtual machine and can extend from `1-300 VMS` randomly throughout the day.

How do I pass the task to the workers?

Is dask recommended for this type of task?

```py
# Server
from distributed import Client
client = Client(
  processes=True,
  threads_per_worker=1,
  n_workers=0
)
with open("file-list.txt", "r") as f:
  data = f.readlines()
for f in data:
  client.submit(myfunc, f)
client
```

```py
# Clients?
from distributed import Client
client = Client(
  "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8786",
  threads_per_worker=1,
  n_workers=1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set up the Dask client, scheduler, and workers using instructions from here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup.html

Then I would probably use the `Client.map` function to call a function on every filename

```
from dask.distributed import Client

client = Client("tcp://scheduler-address:8786")

filenames = ...

def process(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        text = f.read()

    # do things with text

client.map(process, filenames)
```

Comment: you're missing both question. 

The task is the filename string, how does that get passed to the workers. 
`filename = client.current_string` ? I'm just put something random as an example because obviously `...` is not python code
The second question being, is it even the easiest way to accomplish this sort of task?

Comment: The clients should not submit the filenames to process at all, because the big list is known and I don't want a bunch of workers submitting the same list of files to process everytime a new worker is booted.

Comment: There is only one client.  There are many workers.  In this example the client gets the list of filenames (you have to have this somewhere) and then submits many tasks with one filename per task.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out!**

This is meant to run on many different computers, but worked locally. This task will be running for months. I hope I will be able to report back with results.

On the **scheduler machine**, run this:
`dask-scheduler`

On **worker machines** (run this script for as many works as you need)

```py
import asyncio
from distributed import Worker

async def f():
  async with Worker("localhost:8786",) as w:
    await w.finished()


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(f())
```

Add the tasks for **another machine** if you want, or just do it on the **scheduler machine**.

```py
import asyncio
from dask.distributed import Client

def testing(filename):
  # Example function to see if it would work.
  # Not sure how it will work with packages yet.
  with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("worked")
  return True

async def f():

  with open("file-list.txt") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

  async with Client("localhost:8786", asynchronous=True) as client:
    future = client.map(testing, data)
    result = [print(await iterator) for iterator in future]


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(f())
```